# KSQL stream-table join unit test

Tags: ksqldb

I am looking to test my KSQL scripts which involves stream-table join based on a input topic.What is the option available here?

Answer (score 0):

There is a feature request for building a testing framework for KSQL: https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/2103

You may want to chime in with your preference there since it is under active development at the moment.